# Improve speed of search in a large table over million records?

Tags: sql, sql-server, clustered-index

I have a table with the following schema

```
CREATE TABLE [Positions]
(
    [ID_1] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ID_2] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [ID_3] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [ID_4] [varchar](3) NOT NULL,
     // ...... extra columns
    [time] [datetime] NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [pk_Positions] 
       PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID_1] ASC, [ID_2] ASC, [ID_3] ASC, [ID_4] ASC)
```

Around 50K records are inserted multiple times at different time in a day and for a particular insert the `ID_1` value remains the same. The problem is to filter data from a particular time on a day where time specifies the time of insert which is also same for 50k insert.

Now I have a clustered index on `ID_1` and if I query with the `ID_1` value, it's going to be quick but what about time value can I query with time value as it's the same for all the 50K inserts. Will the time column not being an index slow down the query in comparison to `ID_1` column?

Comment: I suspect you know the answer here. And if not you could easily test it out right?

Comment: Theoretically will there be a time difference in this specific case where all the rows will be together for both the columns(ID_1 and datetime). ID_column being an index. Will it create a difference.?

Comment: A difference in what? When you query a non-indexed column it means the engine has to perform a scan instead of a seek. I am not really sure what you are asking here to be honest. Why not test out your queries in your test environment and test the differences in performance.

Comment: @vivekverma . . . The database doesn't know that time is correlated with the id.  It has to look through all the data to find data from the right time.

Comment: To improve performance you will need to either index time, or select ID_1 where time = search_value, then search with the ID_1 value just fetched.